# Probability of getting 3 balls in 10 rooms

Tags: probability

There is a group of $9$ people who visit $10$ different rooms together. Each room has $3$ balls, and each person has an equal probability of getting a ball. What is the probability that, after visiting all $10$ different rooms, person $P$ (one of the $9$ people) has EXACTLY $9$ balls.

Note: Each person can only get a max of one ball from each room

Thanks

Comment: Is that a particular person, or just any one of the 9? If the people are Alan, Barry, Conrad, Dave, Edgar, Fred, Geoff, Herb and Ian, are you asking for example "What's the probability of Fred getting 9 balls?"

Comment: Oh yes, and - welcome to MSE, where people tend to like to see what progress you have made on a problem like this, so they can answer at an appropriate level. Feel free to edit your post to include your thoughts so far on this problem.

Comment: It's a binomial with $p=3/10$, $n=10$ and you want the probability that $x=9$.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that in each room the three balls are distributed to the 9 people so that in each room three get one ball and six get none.
It's a binomial with $p=3/9$, $n=10$ and you want the probability that $x=9$.  So $${10\choose9}\left(\frac3{9}\right)^9\left(\frac{6}{9}\right)^1$$
$$=0.0003951520488633732$$

Answer (score 0):

Person P and eight others enter a room with three balls.  Assuming that everyone has an equal probability of getting any ball, that all three balls are taken, and that nobody gets more than one ball, the probability that Person P gets a ball is $1/3$.

Further assuming this situation is repeated independently in each of the following rooms (that the number of balls already collected does not affect the probability of receiving any others) then the count of balls person P receives has a binomial distribution with parameters $n=10$ and $p=1/3$.

---

On the other hand if more than one ball can be picked up by any person in each room, then the count of balls picked up by person P has a binomial distribution with parameters $n=30$ and $p=1/9$.

---

If there is a chance that one or more balls are not picked up in a room, then you need to specify this.